# Each face of Die a different image

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am somewhat unfamiliar with Blender, but I need to edit this .dae file in order to use it in my Xcode project for an iOS app. I would like to edit the die so that each face is a different png or jpg image. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7esdy6t48nbt870/Dices.dae?dl=0

Comment: Yes. This is definitively possible.

Comment: @X-27 How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm sure it is possible. The question only asks if it is or isn't possible :-)

Comment: @X-27 now it doesn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a number of ways:

1) Set a different material to each facing of the die and give each a separate image texture.

2) Make a color stencil texture with a different color on each face, then use it as a factor between the different image textures within the same material.

3) Like above, but use vertex colors.

Comment: I am having trouble saving it with the same camera and lighting as the original file I imported...