# Convenient method to select different textures on the faces of a die

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

The situation:
I need to create different renders of (normal shaped, 6-sided) dice.
However, the faces don't show the numbers 1 - 6 but a set of characters (i.e. 6 characters out of A – Z). Each die is different, there could be a die with `H,L,O,P,M,R` on the sides or one with `E,A,Q,I,O,P`.

Best case scenario: I'm looking for a method in which I

1. don't need to make 26 different materials as i maybe need to tweak
   the materials later
2. don't have to offset the UV for each face

I' m thinking maybe to input the textures as image sequence – but I don't know if I can say "face 1, use #18 of the image sequence".

Any solutions?

Answers like [Each face of Die a different image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28204/each-face-of-die-a-different-image) don't really help as I know how to apply different materials or textures to individual faces.

Comment: Hi. If a different question doesn't help please say *why* it doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a node group with input for six image textures, then internally it maps each texture to the correct face by "filtering" faces according to normals with a *Input > Geometry > Normal Node*

Comment: Thats actually not a bad idea. I'd still have to make a material for each die but I think its convenient enough in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same Video on each face, but with different time delay?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/same-video-on-each-face-but-with-different-time-delay)

Comment: I thought of this question when I asked but didn't find it. But the answer uses different materials for each face, so this is actually worse for my case then just making a separate material for each face of every die and manually exchange the texture. Duartes method works for me for now.